# select from params for nil class rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, drop-down-menu, haml, parameters

i have a line of code like this :

```
u = params[:collection].select { |k,v| v["id"].present? }
```

and in views, i would like to make a dropdown list that containt this params, like this :

```
select("merge_candidate[#{user.id}]", "id", @users.select { |u| u.id != dc.id }.map { |u| ["#{u.realname} / #{u.email} [id: #{u.id}]", u.id]}, {:selected => selected_user })
```

but, i dont understand why i got error "private method `select' called for nil:NilClass
". any idea? thanks in advance

Comment: Are you sure the `selected_user` variable is available?

Comment: yes, like this : 
selected_user = @users.select { |us| us.id != dc.id }.try(:id)

Comment: Hmmm okay - what about the variable `dc`?

Comment: dc comes from @users.each do |dc|

Comment: what about `@users.select`? I've not seen this function before! What does it do?

Comment: this function? do you mean 'each' function? to select each user from @users

Comment: In your second code block, you have a reference to `@users.select` (it's after "id"), what do you want to accomplish with this? I've never seen `.select` before!

Comment: http://apidock.com/ruby/Hash/select something like that

Comment: Ah okay! Seems the problem is caused by that particular function, but also seems your code is okay. It seems you're trying to extract the `first name` & `last name` of the user where the id = the current user ID. Maybe you could try a `.where`?

Comment: hmm, or maybe my question right now is,
i would like to make dropdown of user ids that pass from params.
could i do like this :
@ controller >> u = User.pluck(:id)
@ views >>>
 - selected_user = @users_id.select
 = select_tag("candidate[#{id}]", option_for_select(@u, selected_user))
or how?

Comment: Couple of possibilities: your `@users` variable is nil, or the select found here is wrong: `select("merge_cand [...])`. Please include details of where `@users` is being defined, and confirm it is available within your view.